# Can I execute a script before every login

Tags: scripting, python, login

I am planning to have a program that will need to connect to a server. I'd like to be able to send a encrypted password to my server. The thing is, I need my decrypting script to be executed (everytime I need to login, not only at boot) before login in.

Is that possible?

To sum up:

- How to have a script executed **BEFORE** login script

  (Because I need the password to be decrypted before it can be entered)

Comment: If its global then put it in `/etc/profile.d/`, if its user specific source it from `~/.profile` (or whatever file your shell reads upon login)..

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays, almost every login-related software relies on pam, so it may be a good idea to use [pam_exec](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec) module to execute your command after the login request to pam (and thus, before the return to the application).

You may also look directly at pam modules, like described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202078/can-a-pam-module-modify-the-password-typed-by-the-user-before-it-is-seen-by-othe).

Comment: thats not true..unless intentionally sourced, `~/.profile` is sourced only for login-interactive shells..

Comment: That's correct, but as we're talking about login scripts, I expect the user to be in interactive mode. Also, ~/.profile is working for ksh and boune. For bash it's ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Guys, my answer is "pam_exec"... You focused on .profile while i know it's not a valid answer for this use... I edited the reply so you can focus on my first and only answer : play with PAM.